# map view inside table view cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview, tableview, android-mapview

i have another (probably unanswered) question about map views. I have a map view inside a table view cell and i want to disable the table view scrolling if the scrolling begins in the map view. Also the zooming gesture does not function normally. It only functions if the zooming gesture is done horizontally on the iphone display. The same thing happens with swiping gestures. It only affects the map if i swipe the map area horizontally. If i swipe vertically the table view scrolls instead, and i want to disable that. Any ides how to do it?

Comment: Why would you need a map view **inside** a table view cell? Sounds like bad design to me.

Comment: Just testing not sure if it will be like this in the final app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No i wasn't able to resolve it. In the new iphone os 4.0 beta it is working the way i expected it to work. Scrolling inside the mapview scrolls the mapview and scrolling the table view, outside the mapview scrolls the table view. Scrolling in wasn't that important to me so now scrolling is disabled. But I found [these](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW5) in the change notes for v3.2 of the SDK. There is the [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) base class and there is a concrete [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Don't know how useful they are but I would try them if I had more time. I would try to detect zooming and moving gestures and would update the mapview with the data i got from these recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not 100% sure but I think you can stop the scrolling using: `UITableView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

Also, I'm also pretty sure that you cannot use Gestures on a CustomTableCell although there may be work arounds for this.

I hope that has shed at least a little bit of light on the subject for you.